# Behaviour of Vue Transition-group

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am new to transition in Vue. I am trying hide and show divs depends on the condition. Can anyone tell me if this is the desired behavior?

```
<div id="app">
  <transition-group name="testanim">
    <p key="1" v-if='open1' @click='open1 = false'>First Block</p>
    <p key="2" v-if='!open1' @click='open1 = true'>Second Block</p>
  </transition-group>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
     return {
        open1: true
     }
  }
})
```

Link for JSfiddle is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gkbLspf2/10/)

Problem is the second div first appears and then moves up. Is there anyway to make it appear in place of first without jumping effect and with transition?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `transition-group` in this case. Also you need to use `mode="out-in"`

Reference: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transition-Modes

```
<div id="app">
  <transition name="testanim" mode="out-in">
   <p key="1" v-if='open1' @click='open1 = false'>First Block</p>
   <p key="2" v-if='!open1' @click='open1 = true'>Second Block</p>
 </transition>
</div>
```

Comment: @Pradeepb though in the accepted answer you loose the "exit effect"

Comment: I agree. I felt your answer is more appropriate for my use-case.

Answer (score 1):

Split your transition for `leave` and `enter` separate and keep `leave` as `0s` to not take any time to leave.

```js
Vue.component("test-sth", {
  template: `
    <transition name='testanim'>
      <p v-if='open' @click='open = !open'>Can You See Me?</p>
    </transition>
  `,
  data: () => ({
    open: true,
  }),
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
  return {
  open1: true,
  open2: true,
  }
  }
})
```

```css
.testanim-leave-active {
  transition: all 0s;
}

.testanim-enter-active{
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.testanim-enter,
.testanim-leave-to {
  transform: translateX(1rem);
  opacity: 0;
}

.testanim-leave-active {
  /* position: absolute; */
}

.testanim-move {
  transition: all .5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <transition-group name="testanim">
  <p key="1" v-if='open1' @click='open1 = false'>First Block</p>
  <p key="2" v-if='!open1' @click='open1 = true'>Second Block</p>
</transition-group>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution. :-)